# want to migrate the data from one model to other model based on the criteria - java stream API

Tags: java-8, java-stream

StepResponseNew.java

```
step_response_new_id -- primary key
tag_record_id --Foreign key
step_name
step_value
comments
..
```

StepResponse.java

```
step_response_id -- primary key
parent_id -- Foreign key
step_name
step_value
comments
..
```

TagRecordsEntity.java

```
tag_records_id -- primary key
parent_id -- foreign ID
..
```

The requirement is i want to copy all the data from StepResponse to StepResponseNew where the first two properties are different in both of these classes.
I have a Map which has id (parent_id) as key and `List<StepResponse>`as value as shown below.

```
 Map<Long, List<StepResponse>> stepEntityMap = stepResponseList.stream().
                collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                        stepResponse ->  stepResponse.getStepId()
                ));
```

I have a List of TagRecords

```
List<TagRecordsEntity> tagRecordsEntityList = recordsRepository.findAll();
```

Now i want to iterate the above tagRecordsEntityList, and for each parent_id is in stepEntityMap key, i want to get the tag_record_id for the Parent_id and set the values in StepResponseNew

```
 List<StepResponseNew> stepResponseNew  = new ArrayList<>();
        for (TagRecordsEntity recordsEntity : recordsEntityList){
            if (stepEntityMap.containsKey(recordsEntity.getRecordId())) {
                List<StepResponse> stepResponseList1 = stepEntityMap.get(recordsEntity.getRecordId());
                //want to set  stepResponseList1 few properties in stepResponseNew 
            }
        }
```

Want the input on how to migrate the data from StepRepsonse to StepResponseNew.

Comment: It would be nicer if you would replace these lists of database column-names with proper Java-classes.

Comment: And it's not completely clear what's the issue with generating `StepResponseNew` based on `StepRepsonse`.